# Error connecting to Local Database con.open()

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have the sample database `Northwind` installed and attached to a C# project

I'm trying to connect to the database and retrieve column names of a table in the database, but I'm getting an error while trying to open the connection, here is the code I'm using to do so:

```
public void connectToDB()
{
     Dictionary<object, object> colns = new Dictionary<object, object>();
     List<string> colnNames = new List<string>();
     con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = .NorthwindDB.mdf; Integrated Security=True");
     con.Open();
     cmd = con.CreateCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Products";
     adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     ds = new DataSet();
     adapter.Fill(ds);
     dt = ds.Tables["Products"];
     foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
     {
         foreach(DataColumn dc in dr.Table.Columns)
         {
             colnNames.Add(dc.ColumnName.ToString());
         }
     }
     foreach(string key in colnNames)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(key.ToString());
     }
     Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Another thing that may help, I'm noticing that whenever I click `start` button to execute the code, the green plug that appears over the data connection `NorthwindDB.mdf` turns into red x.

Comment: `NorthwindDB.mdf` is not `Data Source`.

Comment: could you please explain more? so what is it? I'm new to this programming language :) @user2946329

Comment: Sorry for the delay @user2946329, I've found a way to get the connectionString value by copying it from the properties panel of the mdf file, I just added double slashes inside the path string. Anyways thanks so much for your help and patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection string is incorrect it should be something like this:

```
con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);" +
                         "Initial Catalog=NorthwindDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
// Or Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;
```

You can read more about connection strings here: [`Database Connectionstrings`](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/connection-strings).